# Catch event of show and hide dataset at chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chart.JS with chartjs-plugin-annotation for drawing base line in chart bar. And I wanna hide it ( this red line) when hide first data set.

```
let data1 = {
            labels: charts['str-err'].labels,
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Strength',
              data: charts['str-err'].data,
              backgroundColor: ['rgba(0,102,204,0.5)']
            },{
              label: 'Avg data, %',
              data: p_model,
              backgroundColor: ['rgba(0,102,204,0.6)']
            }]
          };

        let options = {
            scales: {
              x: {
                grid: {
                  drawBorder: false,
                  display: false,
                }
              },
              y: {
                grid: {
                  drawBorder: false,
                  display: true,
                  drawOnChartArea: true,
                  drawTicks: false,
                  borderDash: [5, 5]
                }
              }
            },
            plugins: {
               legend:{align: 'start'},
               annotation: {
                   annotations: {
                       line1: {
                           type: 'line',
                           yMin: avg_err,
                           yMax: avg_err,
                           borderColor: 'rgba(234,6,6,0.7)',
                           borderWidth: 1,
                           borderDash: [2,2],
                           display: true
                       }
                   }
               }
            },
        };
```

I wanna hide line1 when 'Strength' dataset was hidden, and turn it back when show 'Strength' chart bar. I know how to hide line1 but can't understand how to catch event that dataset was hidden

```
let displayAnnotation = function(chart, d){
                       chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.line1.display = d;
                       chart.update();
            };
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the legend `onClick` handler like so:

```js
const defaultLegendClickHandler = Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick;
const pieDoughnutLegendClickHandler = Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.onClick;

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Strength',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: 'Avg data, %',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onClick: (evt, legendItem, legend) => {
          const type = legend.chart.config.type;

          if (type === 'pie' || type === 'doughnut') {
            pieDoughnutLegendClickHandler(evt, legendItem, legend)
          } else {
            defaultLegendClickHandler(evt, legendItem, legend);
          }

          if (legendItem.text !== 'Strength') {
            return;
          }

          legend.chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.line1.display = !legend.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden;
          legend.chart.update();
        }
      },
      annotation: {
        annotations: {
          line1: {
            type: 'line',
            yMin: 4,
            yMax: 6,
            borderColor: 'rgba(234,6,6,0.7)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderDash: [2, 2],
            display: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.0.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
</body>
```